# How do I use multiple levels in my REST call?

Tags: rest

I'm trying to create a REST service with the following signature for a GET call:

//somesite/api/customer/1/invoices

Of course using the correct path, I can get this to work, but all the documentation that I look at for REST tells me how to query .../api/customer or .../api/customer/id, but nothing tells me how to define and get to the level after id.

I suspect it will have something to do with the router code, but could use some instruction on how to get to that next level.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using COBOL, or...?

Comment: Using C# and I should clarify that this is Web API flavor of REST.